# What is the VTable Layout and VTable Pointer Location in C++ Objects in GCC 3.x and 4.x?

Tags: c++, g++

I am looking for details of the VTable structure, order and contents, and the location of the vtable pointers within objects.

Ideally, this will cover single inheritance, multiple inheritance, and virtual inheritance.

References to external documentation would also be appreciated

Documentation of GCC 4.0x class layout is [here](https://ww2.ii.uj.edu.pl/%7Ekapela/pn/cpp_vtable.html#virtual) and the Itanium, and more broadly GNU, ABI layout documents are [here](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#general).

Comment: This is probably described in [C++ ABI](http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/). E.g., [C++ VTable examples](http://mentorembedded.github.com/cxx-abi/abi-examples.html).

Comment: Have you tried gcc's '-fdump-class-hierarchy' option?

Comment: The former link is dead! D:

Answer (score 13):

A virtual table is generally treated as an array of function pointers, although compilers are free to put data pointers (in MI and VI scenarios, or to typeinfos), integers (for fixups), or sentinel elements (such as NULL pointers) into it as well.  The layout is generally compiler-specific (or ABI-specific where multiple C++ compilers share an ABI), but stable provided the classes being compiled have stable interfaces (otherwise you'd have to recompile your code all the time, and that's a drag).  There are also additional tables that are needed to handle corner cases involving virtual and multiple inheritance, and to make sure that virtual calls during derived class construction behave as the Standard says they should under those circumstances (those are what the VTTs and construction tables in the output below are for).

As to the specific case of GCC 4.x: the `-fdump-class-hierarchy` switch indeed acts as described (and then some).  I tested it on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16d53eb062d38bec) using the sample code below:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct OtherBase
{
    virtual ~OtherBase() {}
    virtual void g() {}
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    virtual ~Derived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct MultiplyDerived: public Base, public OtherBase
{
    virtual ~MultiplyDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
    virtual void g() {}
};

struct OtherDerived: public Base
{
    virtual ~OtherDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct DiamondDerived: public Derived, public OtherDerived
{
    virtual ~DiamondDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct VirtuallyDerived: virtual public Base
{
    virtual ~VirtuallyDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct OtherVirtuallyDerived: virtual public Base
{
    virtual ~OtherVirtuallyDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct VirtuallyDiamondDerived: public VirtuallyDerived, public OtherVirtuallyDerived
{
    virtual ~VirtuallyDiamondDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived: virtual public VirtuallyDerived, virtual public OtherVirtuallyDerived
{
    virtual ~DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct MixedVirtuallyDerived: virtual public Base, public OtherBase
{
    virtual ~MixedVirtuallyDerived() {}
};

struct MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived: public VirtuallyDerived, public MixedVirtuallyDerived
{
    virtual ~MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
    virtual void g() {}
};

struct VirtuallyMultiplyDerived: virtual public Base, virtual public OtherBase
{
    virtual ~VirtuallyMultiplyDerived() {}
};

struct OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived: virtual public Base, virtual public OtherBase
{
    virtual ~OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived() {}
};

struct MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived: public VirtuallyMultiplyDerived, public OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived
{
    virtual ~MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived() {}
    virtual void f() {}
    virtual void g() {}
};
```

and received from G++ (mangled name guide: TI's are typeinfos, TV's are vtables, and Th's and Tv's are thunks used to make correct virtual calls in the presence of multiple and/or virtual inheritance):

```
Vtable for Base

Base::_ZTV4Base: 5u entries

0     (int (*)(...))0

8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI4Base)

16    0u

24    0u

32    (int (*)(...))__cxa_pure_virtual


Class Base

   size=8 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

Base (0x0x7fd42c0355a0) 0 nearly-empty

    vptr=((& Base::_ZTV4Base) + 16u)


Vtable for OtherBase

OtherBase::_ZTV9OtherBase: 5u entries

0     (int (*)(...))0

8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI9OtherBase)

16    (int (*)(...))OtherBase::~OtherBase

24    (int (*)(...))OtherBase::~OtherBase

32    (int (*)(...))OtherBase::g


Class OtherBase

   size=8 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

OtherBase (0x0x7fd42c035600) 0 nearly-empty

    vptr=((& OtherBase::_ZTV9OtherBase) + 16u)


Vtable for Derived

Derived::_ZTV7Derived: 5u entries

0     (int (*)(...))0

8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI7Derived)

16    (int (*)(...))Derived::~Derived

24    (int (*)(...))Derived::~Derived

32    (int (*)(...))Derived::f


Class Derived

   size=8 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

Derived (0x0x7fd42c02d138) 0 nearly-empty

    vptr=((& Derived::_ZTV7Derived) + 16u)

  Base (0x0x7fd42c035660) 0 nearly-empty

      primary-for Derived (0x0x7fd42c02d138)


Vtable for MultiplyDerived

MultiplyDerived::_ZTV15MultiplyDerived: 11u entries

0     (int (*)(...))0

8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI15MultiplyDerived)

16    (int (*)(...))MultiplyDerived::~MultiplyDerived

24    (int (*)(...))MultiplyDerived::~MultiplyDerived

32    (int (*)(...))MultiplyDerived::f

40    (int (*)(...))MultiplyDerived::g

48    (int (*)(...))-8

56    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI15MultiplyDerived)

64    (int (*)(...))MultiplyDerived::_ZThn8_N15MultiplyDerivedD1Ev

72    (int (*)(...))MultiplyDerived::_ZThn8_N15MultiplyDerivedD0Ev

80    (int (*)(...))MultiplyDerived::_ZThn8_N15MultiplyDerived1gEv


Class MultiplyDerived

   size=16 align=8

   base size=16 base align=8

MultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42c04aaf0) 0

    vptr=((& MultiplyDerived::_ZTV15MultiplyDerived) + 16u)

  Base (0x0x7fd42c0356c0) 0 nearly-empty

      primary-for MultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42c04aaf0)

  OtherBase (0x0x7fd42c035720) 8 nearly-empty

      vptr=((& MultiplyDerived::_ZTV15MultiplyDerived) + 64u)


Vtable for OtherDerived

OtherDerived::_ZTV12OtherDerived: 5u entries

0     (int (*)(...))0

8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI12OtherDerived)

16    (int (*)(...))OtherDerived::~OtherDerived

24    (int (*)(...))OtherDerived::~OtherDerived

32    (int (*)(...))OtherDerived::f


Class OtherDerived

   size=8 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

OtherDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d1a0) 0 nearly-empty

    vptr=((& OtherDerived::_ZTV12OtherDerived) + 16u)

  Base (0x0x7fd42c035780) 0 nearly-empty

      primary-for OtherDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d1a0)


Vtable for DiamondDerived

DiamondDerived::_ZTV14DiamondDerived: 10u entries

0     (int (*)(...))0

8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI14DiamondDerived)

16    (int (*)(...))DiamondDerived::~DiamondDerived

24    (int (*)(...))DiamondDerived::~DiamondDerived

32    (int (*)(...))DiamondDerived::f

40    (int (*)(...))-8

48    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI14DiamondDerived)

56    (int (*)(...))DiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N14DiamondDerivedD1Ev

64    (int (*)(...))DiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N14DiamondDerivedD0Ev

72    (int (*)(...))DiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N14DiamondDerived1fEv


Class DiamondDerived

   size=16 align=8

   base size=16 base align=8

DiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42c0625b0) 0

    vptr=((& DiamondDerived::_ZTV14DiamondDerived) + 16u)

  Derived (0x0x7fd42c02d208) 0 nearly-empty

      primary-for DiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42c0625b0)

    Base (0x0x7fd42c0357e0) 0 nearly-empty

        primary-for Derived (0x0x7fd42c02d208)

  OtherDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d270) 8 nearly-empty

      vptr=((& DiamondDerived::_ZTV14DiamondDerived) + 56u)

    Base (0x0x7fd42c035840) 8 nearly-empty

        primary-for OtherDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d270)


Vtable for VirtuallyDerived

VirtuallyDerived::_ZTV16VirtuallyDerived: 8u entries

0     0u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI16VirtuallyDerived)

40    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDerived::~VirtuallyDerived

48    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDerived::~VirtuallyDerived

56    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDerived::f


VTT for VirtuallyDerived

VirtuallyDerived::_ZTT16VirtuallyDerived: 2u entries

0     ((& VirtuallyDerived::_ZTV16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

8     ((& VirtuallyDerived::_ZTV16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)


Class VirtuallyDerived

   size=8 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d2d8) 0 nearly-empty

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& VirtuallyDerived::_ZTV16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

  Base (0x0x7fd42c0358a0) 0 nearly-empty virtual

      primary-for VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d2d8)

      vptridx=8u vbaseoffset=-40


Vtable for OtherVirtuallyDerived

OtherVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21OtherVirtuallyDerived: 8u entries

0     0u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21OtherVirtuallyDerived)

40    (int (*)(...))OtherVirtuallyDerived::~OtherVirtuallyDerived

48    (int (*)(...))OtherVirtuallyDerived::~OtherVirtuallyDerived

56    (int (*)(...))OtherVirtuallyDerived::f


VTT for OtherVirtuallyDerived

OtherVirtuallyDerived::_ZTT21OtherVirtuallyDerived: 2u entries

0     ((& OtherVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21OtherVirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

8     ((& OtherVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21OtherVirtuallyDerived) + 40u)


Class OtherVirtuallyDerived

   size=8 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

OtherVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d340) 0 nearly-empty

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& OtherVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21OtherVirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

  Base (0x0x7fd42c035900) 0 nearly-empty virtual

      primary-for OtherVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d340)

      vptridx=8u vbaseoffset=-40


Vtable for VirtuallyDiamondDerived

VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV23VirtuallyDiamondDerived: 16u entries

0     0u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI23VirtuallyDiamondDerived)

40    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDiamondDerived::~VirtuallyDiamondDerived

48    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDiamondDerived::~VirtuallyDiamondDerived

56    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDiamondDerived::f

64    18446744073709551608u

72    18446744073709551608u

80    18446744073709551608u

88    (int (*)(...))-8

96    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI23VirtuallyDiamondDerived)

104   (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N23VirtuallyDiamondDerivedD1Ev

112   (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N23VirtuallyDiamondDerivedD0Ev

120   (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N23VirtuallyDiamondDerived1fEv


Construction vtable for VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d3a8 instance) in VirtuallyDiamondDerived

VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC23VirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived: 8u entries

0     0u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI16VirtuallyDerived)

40    0u

48    0u

56    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDerived::f


Construction vtable for OtherVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d410 instance) in VirtuallyDiamondDerived

VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC23VirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21OtherVirtuallyDerived: 15u entries

0     18446744073709551608u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21OtherVirtuallyDerived)

40    0u

48    0u

56    (int (*)(...))OtherVirtuallyDerived::f

64    8u

72    8u

80    (int (*)(...))8

88    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21OtherVirtuallyDerived)

96    0u

104   0u

112   (int (*)(...))OtherVirtuallyDerived::_ZTv0_n32_N21OtherVirtuallyDerived1fEv


VTT for VirtuallyDiamondDerived

VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTT23VirtuallyDiamondDerived: 7u entries

0     ((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV23VirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 40u)

8     ((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC23VirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

16    ((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC23VirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

24    ((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC23VirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21OtherVirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

32    ((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC23VirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21OtherVirtuallyDerived) + 96u)

40    ((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV23VirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 40u)

48    ((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV23VirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 104u)


Class VirtuallyDiamondDerived

   size=16 align=8

   base size=16 base align=8

VirtuallyDiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42c07e460) 0

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV23VirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 40u)

  VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d3a8) 0 nearly-empty

      primary-for VirtuallyDiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42c07e460)

      subvttidx=8u

    Base (0x0x7fd42c035960) 0 nearly-empty virtual

        primary-for VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d3a8)

        vptridx=40u vbaseoffset=-40

  OtherVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d410) 8 nearly-empty

      lost-primary

      subvttidx=24u vptridx=48u vptr=((& VirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV23VirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 104u)

    Base (0x0x7fd42c035960) alternative-path


Vtable for DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived: 18u entries

0     8u

8     0u

16    0u

24    0u

32    0u

40    (int (*)(...))0

48    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived)

56    (int (*)(...))DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::~DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

64    (int (*)(...))DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::~DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

72    (int (*)(...))DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::f

80    18446744073709551608u

88    18446744073709551608u

96    18446744073709551608u

104   (int (*)(...))-8

112   (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived)

120   (int (*)(...))DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTv0_n24_N29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerivedD1Ev

128   (int (*)(...))DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTv0_n24_N29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerivedD0Ev

136   (int (*)(...))DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTv0_n32_N29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived1fEv


Construction vtable for VirtuallyDerived in DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived: 8u entries

0     0u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI16VirtuallyDerived)

40    0u

48    0u

56    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDerived::f


Construction vtable for OtherVirtuallyDerived in DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21OtherVirtuallyDerived: 15u entries

0     18446744073709551608u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21OtherVirtuallyDerived)

40    0u

48    0u

56    (int (*)(...))OtherVirtuallyDerived::f

64    8u

72    8u

80    (int (*)(...))8

88    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21OtherVirtuallyDerived)

96    0u

104   0u

112   (int (*)(...))OtherVirtuallyDerived::_ZTv0_n32_N21OtherVirtuallyDerived1fEv


VTT for DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTT29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived: 8u entries

0     ((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 56u)

8     ((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 56u)

16    ((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 56u)

24    ((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 120u)

32    ((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

40    ((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

48    ((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21OtherVirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

56    ((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21OtherVirtuallyDerived) + 96u)


Class DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

   size=16 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42c07ea10) 0 nearly-empty

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 56u)

  VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d478) 0 nearly-empty virtual

      primary-for DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42c07ea10)

      subvttidx=32u vptridx=8u vbaseoffset=-48

    Base (0x0x7fd42c035a80) 0 nearly-empty virtual

        primary-for VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d478)

        vptridx=16u vbaseoffset=-40

  OtherVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d4e0) 8 nearly-empty virtual

      lost-primary

      subvttidx=48u vptridx=24u vbaseoffset=-56 vptr=((& DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV29DoublyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 120u)

    Base (0x0x7fd42c035a80) alternative-path


Vtable for MixedVirtuallyDerived

MixedVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21MixedVirtuallyDerived: 13u entries

0     8u

8     (int (*)(...))0

16    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21MixedVirtuallyDerived)

24    0u

32    0u

40    (int (*)(...))OtherBase::g

48    0u

56    18446744073709551608u

64    (int (*)(...))-8

72    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21MixedVirtuallyDerived)

80    0u

88    0u

96    (int (*)(...))__cxa_pure_virtual


VTT for MixedVirtuallyDerived

MixedVirtuallyDerived::_ZTT21MixedVirtuallyDerived: 2u entries

0     ((& MixedVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21MixedVirtuallyDerived) + 24u)

8     ((& MixedVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21MixedVirtuallyDerived) + 80u)


Class MixedVirtuallyDerived

   size=16 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

MixedVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c07eee0) 0 nearly-empty

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& MixedVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21MixedVirtuallyDerived) + 24u)

  Base (0x0x7fd42c035c60) 8 nearly-empty virtual

      vptridx=8u vbaseoffset=-24 vptr=((& MixedVirtuallyDerived::_ZTV21MixedVirtuallyDerived) + 80u)

  OtherBase (0x0x7fd42c035cc0) 0 nearly-empty

      primary-for MixedVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c07eee0)


Vtable for MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived

MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived: 15u entries

0     0u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived)

40    (int (*)(...))MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::~MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived

48    (int (*)(...))MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::~MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived

56    (int (*)(...))MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::f

64    (int (*)(...))MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::g

72    18446744073709551608u

80    (int (*)(...))-8

88    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived)

96    (int (*)(...))MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerivedD1Ev

104   (int (*)(...))MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerivedD0Ev

112   (int (*)(...))MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived1gEv


Construction vtable for VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d750 instance) in MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived

MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived: 8u entries

0     0u

8     0u

16    0u

24    (int (*)(...))0

32    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI16VirtuallyDerived)

40    0u

48    0u

56    (int (*)(...))VirtuallyDerived::f


Construction vtable for MixedVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b5380 instance) in MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived

MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21MixedVirtuallyDerived: 13u entries

0     18446744073709551608u

8     (int (*)(...))0

16    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21MixedVirtuallyDerived)

24    0u

32    0u

40    (int (*)(...))OtherBase::g

48    0u

56    8u

64    (int (*)(...))8

72    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI21MixedVirtuallyDerived)

80    0u

88    0u

96    (int (*)(...))__cxa_pure_virtual


VTT for MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived

MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTT28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived: 7u entries

0     ((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 40u)

8     ((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

16    ((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_16VirtuallyDerived) + 40u)

24    ((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21MixedVirtuallyDerived) + 24u)

32    ((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_21MixedVirtuallyDerived) + 80u)

40    ((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 40u)

48    ((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 96u)


Class MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived

   size=16 align=8

   base size=16 base align=8

MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b5310) 0

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 40u)

  VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d750) 0 nearly-empty

      primary-for MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b5310)

      subvttidx=8u

    Base (0x0x7fd42c035d20) 0 nearly-empty virtual

        primary-for VirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c02d750)

        vptridx=40u vbaseoffset=-40

  MixedVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b5380) 8 nearly-empty

      subvttidx=24u vptridx=48u vptr=((& MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV28MixedVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 96u)

    Base (0x0x7fd42c035d20) alternative-path

    OtherBase (0x0x7fd42c035d80) 8 nearly-empty

        primary-for MixedVirtuallyDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b5380)


Vtable for VirtuallyMultiplyDerived

VirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived: 16u entries

0     8u

8     0u

16    0u

24    0u

32    (int (*)(...))0

40    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

48    0u

56    0u

64    (int (*)(...))__cxa_pure_virtual

72    0u

80    18446744073709551608u

88    (int (*)(...))-8

96    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

104   0u

112   0u

120   (int (*)(...))OtherBase::g


VTT for VirtuallyMultiplyDerived

VirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTT24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived: 3u entries

0     ((& VirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

8     ((& VirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

16    ((& VirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 104u)


Class VirtuallyMultiplyDerived

   size=16 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

VirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b59a0) 0 nearly-empty

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& VirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

  Base (0x0x7fd42c035e40) 0 nearly-empty virtual

      primary-for VirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b59a0)

      vptridx=8u vbaseoffset=-40

  OtherBase (0x0x7fd42c035ea0) 8 nearly-empty virtual

      vptridx=16u vbaseoffset=-48 vptr=((& VirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 104u)


Vtable for OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived

OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived: 16u entries

0     8u

8     0u

16    0u

24    0u

32    (int (*)(...))0

40    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

48    0u

56    0u

64    (int (*)(...))__cxa_pure_virtual

72    0u

80    18446744073709551608u

88    (int (*)(...))-8

96    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

104   0u

112   0u

120   (int (*)(...))OtherBase::g


VTT for OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived

OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTT29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived: 3u entries

0     ((& OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

8     ((& OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

16    ((& OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 104u)


Class OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived

   size=16 align=8

   base size=8 base align=8

OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b5d90) 0 nearly-empty

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

  Base (0x0x7fd42c035f00) 0 nearly-empty virtual

      primary-for OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42c0b5d90)

      vptridx=8u vbaseoffset=-40

  OtherBase (0x0x7fd42c035f60) 8 nearly-empty virtual

      vptridx=16u vbaseoffset=-48 vptr=((& OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived::_ZTV29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 104u)


Vtable for MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived: 26u entries

0     16u

8     0u

16    0u

24    0u

32    (int (*)(...))0

40    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived)

48    (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::~MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

56    (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::~MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

64    (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::f

72    (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::g

80    8u

88    18446744073709551608u

96    18446744073709551608u

104   18446744073709551608u

112   (int (*)(...))-8

120   (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived)

128   (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerivedD1Ev

136   (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZThn8_N31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerivedD0Ev

144   0u

152   18446744073709551600u

160   18446744073709551600u

168   (int (*)(...))-16

176   (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived)

184   (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTv0_n24_N31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerivedD1Ev

192   (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTv0_n24_N31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerivedD0Ev

200   (int (*)(...))MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTv0_n32_N31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived1gEv


Construction vtable for VirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42bcdf230 instance) in MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived: 16u entries

0     16u

8     0u

16    0u

24    0u

32    (int (*)(...))0

40    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

48    0u

56    0u

64    (int (*)(...))__cxa_pure_virtual

72    0u

80    18446744073709551600u

88    (int (*)(...))-16

96    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

104   0u

112   0u

120   (int (*)(...))OtherBase::g


Construction vtable for OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42bcdf2a0 instance) in MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived: 23u entries

0     8u

8     18446744073709551608u

16    18446744073709551608u

24    0u

32    (int (*)(...))0

40    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

48    0u

56    0u

64    (int (*)(...))__cxa_pure_virtual

72    0u

80    8u

88    (int (*)(...))8

96    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

104   0u

112   0u

120   (int (*)(...))__cxa_pure_virtual

128   0u

136   18446744073709551608u

144   (int (*)(...))-8

152   (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived)

160   0u

168   0u

176   (int (*)(...))OtherBase::g


VTT for MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTT31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived: 10u entries

0     ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 48u)

8     ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

16    ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

24    ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived0_24VirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 104u)

32    ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 48u)

40    ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 104u)

48    ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTC31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived8_29OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived) + 160u)

56    ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 48u)

64    ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 184u)

72    ((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 128u)


Class MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived

   size=24 align=8

   base size=16 base align=8

MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42bcdf1c0) 0

    vptridx=0u vptr=((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 48u)

  VirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42bcdf230) 0 nearly-empty

      primary-for MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived (0x0x7fd42bcdf1c0)

      subvttidx=8u

    Base (0x0x7fd42bce2000) 0 nearly-empty virtual

        primary-for VirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42bcdf230)

        vptridx=56u vbaseoffset=-40

    OtherBase (0x0x7fd42bce2060) 16 nearly-empty virtual

        vptridx=64u vbaseoffset=-48 vptr=((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 184u)

  OtherVirtuallyMultiplyDerived (0x0x7fd42bcdf2a0) 8 nearly-empty

      lost-primary

      subvttidx=32u vptridx=72u vptr=((& MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived::_ZTV31MultiplyVirtuallyDiamondDerived) + 128u)

    Base (0x0x7fd42bce2000) alternative-path

    OtherBase (0x0x7fd42bce2060) alternative-path
```

Answer (score -6):

Most of the compiler implementations that I have seen just "embed" the base object into the derived object. It becomes irrelevant where the vtable is kept because the relative offset into the object will just be added at compile time as references are evaluated.

Multiple and virtual inheritance are more complicated and can require a different offset depending on what is being accessed.

I highly recommend reading this article on Code Project: [The Impossibly Fast C++ Delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible)

It brilliantly gives a broad picture of how different compilers handle various aspects of inheritance. Fantastic read if you are interested in the low level workings of different compilers.

Edit: I linked the wrong article over there. Corrected.

Comment: "It becomes irrelevant where the vtable is kept" It seems _very_ relevant. Half of the question was specifically asking where it's kept for different types of inheritance. Saying 'it doesn't matter' for one and 'it's complicated' for the rest isn't an answer. Also, you missed the other half of the question, asking how vtables are structured.

Comment: Also, I fail to see how that article explains how compilers handle inheritance. All it talks about is delegates, which are an orthogonal concept.