# Are virtual function pointers vtable indices?

Tags: c++

As I remember C++ standard says that virtual function pointers should be indices in vtable and they remain valid when passing through different processes. Is it true? Can someone point out and serious source which conforms  that ?

Comment: Could you please clarify "passing through different processes"? Any pointer is certainly only valid in one process' address space at a time, so that applies to vtables/virtual function pointers as well.

Comment: The standard says nothing about a virtual function table, that's an implementation detail left up to the compiler developers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682/what-is-the-vtable-layout-and-vtable-pointer-location-in-c-objects-in-gcc-3-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is certainly no guarantee in the C++ Standard as to the representation or transferability of any type of pointer; the C++ Standard doesn't even have a conception of a multi-process environment. (Note that C++ is used in embedded environments where the concept of multiple processes doesn't exist.)

To determine whether virtual function pointers are transferable across processes, consult your platform ABI.  For example, the [Itanium ABI has](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-pointers):

> A pointer to member function is a pair as follows:
>
> #### ptr:
>
> For a non-virtual function, this field is a simple function pointer. (Under current base Itanium psABI conventions, that is a pointer to a GP/function address pair.) For a virtual function, it is 1 plus the virtual table offset (in bytes) of the function, represented as a `ptrdiff_t`. The value zero represents a NULL pointer, independent of the adjustment field value below.
>
> #### adj:
>
> The required adjustment to this, represented as a `ptrdiff_t`.

So on Itanium, it is possible to transfer a virtual function pointer across processes, as long as the vtable layout is the same in those two processes.

Comment: I have noticed something similar on AOI platform. But if it is not guaranteed by standard I will not relay on that.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not true.

The standard says nothing about how virtual functions / polymorphism should be implemented. It says nothing about multiple processes either.

The description of what *is* a virtual functions in in **§ 10.3** in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to know how the vtable is implemented. There are a lot of different implementations around. Sometimes the vtable itself contains pointers to the target function and the vtable-pointer directly points to that. But compiler vendors can do this in any fashion they want.

Simple answer to your question: You are wrong :-)