# Is there any direct way to get the address of a vtable at compile time?

Tags: c++, gcc, polymorphism, vtable

I am debugging a pernicious memory corruption error, where it looks like a pointer to a `vtable` is getting corrupted. I would like to detect when it happens by comparing the value of the pointer to the correct value of the pointer (true location of the `vtable`) at various points in my program.

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to obtain the correct value of the pointer at compile time, so I have been forced to instantiate a new object just for the sake of reading off its `vtable` pointer, which seems unnecessarily hacky.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdint.h>

class Foo {
    virtual void performVirtualAction() {
        std::cout << "Foo's version" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Bar : public Foo {
    virtual void performVirtualAction() {
        std::cout << "Bar's version" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    std::cout << "Foo's vtable pointer " << std::hex << *(uint64_t*)(&foo) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bar's vtable pointer " << std::hex << *(uint64_t*)(&bar) << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a more direct way to express the idea that I want the location of the `vtable` for a particular type like `Foo` or `Bar`?

The method does not have to be portable. It only has to work for `gcc` on Linux.

Comment: I assume before trying this type of hack you've ran `valgrind`, `asan`, `ubsan`?

Comment: I'm debugging parts of a distributed system.  When I attached valgrind it changed the timing so much I could not reproduce the problem. I haven't yet seen it heard of the other two but will look at them.

Comment: I'll be interested to know if the problem really was vtable corruption.  Anyway, most often, though compiler dependent, the vtable is at the beginning of the object - of these objects you use as an example, for example.  (Where it isn't at the beginning: when the base class has no virtuals, for example.)  Anyway, do you have access to a heap that can detect, in debug mode, overruns by allocating guards ahead and behind of heap allocations?  (MS VC++ has this capability.)  It shouldn't perturb timing much at all (assuming you're not near the machine RAM capacity).

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not define how polymorphism is to be implemented. vtables are just the defacto standard, but if any compiler vendor finds an appropriate different approach, he is free to do whatever he wants.

So whatever you try to do programmatically, it always will stay a dirty hack because the vtable is an internal compiler detail not directly visible to C++ code.

[ Edit: Needed to correct myself: gcc places a pointer to the vtable right at the beginning of a polymorphic class. Following from this: simply cast your object to `uintptr_t` (not `uint64_t`) (or a pointer to `uintptr_t*`) and you will get directly the pointer to the vtable. If you additionally want to print the vtable itself (to see if this one got corrupted), this might help: [What is the VTable Layout and VTable Pointer Location in C++ Objects in GCC 3.x and 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682/what-is-the-vtable-layout-and-vtable-pointer-location-in-c-objects-in-gcc-3-x) ]

Actually, I do not expect that you will find out much as you probably will see a change in the vtable long after it actually happened. If you know or can find out which object instance(s) is/are affected, you could add a memory watchpoint on write access (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) in gdb. This would reveal exactly when and where your vtable is corrupted (e. g. if you write beyond the defined borders of an array, cast your object to wrong type and write to it, ...).

Comment: Please see the note at the bottom of the question regarding portability.  I'm aware that vtable is an implementation detail.

Comment: And I know - the point is - because of being an implementation detail, you won't get a nice C++ way to access it...

Comment: @orenrevenge Why opinion? Implementation details are hid away from the user and fact is that a standard way to access them does not exist (a compiler *might* provide access to as an *extension*, but non of the currently available ones does so). The only way to access such details are hacks that are *not* covered by the standard. That's it, nothing to discuss about. Even worse: As being left to the implementation (i. e. compiler) any one might do the stuff slightly differently in the details, even though the general concept of vtables in practice is well established.

Comment: every C++ book I read stated that polymorphism is acheived via virtual table. Even Bjarne Stroustrop's book state that polymorphism is not very expensive as it is just one vtbale for all classes, and just one indirection. Bjarne Stroustrop clearly states this vtable address is the first member of the class. So I get confused and frustrated when all of a sudden, vtables are not defined in the standard. Is like I want to say; Well F@@k you too Bjarne Stroustrop. And also, I want to state that dynamic_cast is rubbish. It doesnt actually tell you if an object can dynamically cast.

Comment: @user13947194 They are the *de-facto* standard for the implementation. That's why Stroustrop refers to them as well. Still v-tables are not mentioned anywhere in the C++ standard. Try to [find them](https://www.eel.is/c++draft/) yourself ;) And that's the reason, as written already, that there's no language internal tool to access them. That hasn't much to do with the `dynamic_cast`. If a compiler vendor finds an alternative approach that one would have to cover the DC as well. The DC *is* a language tool, so it must be provided, whichever way you go to implement...

Comment: @user13947194 The standard indeed *does* state that DC only can be applied to virtual classes, by the way. Still that doesn't mean the standard would mandate one or another way how it is implemented. Apart from there's a common sense that your programme shouldn't have need of anyway, if it does, that's usually a hint to a more or less severe design flaw...

Comment: @Aconcagua So when books imply that vtables are apart of the standard nothing is wrong with that? Secondly, java's instanceof operator is a complete waste of time because it promotes bad design?

Comment: @user13947194 There's nothing wrong about. Java or C# know about v-tables, too, and hide them away from user as well. I'd assume pretty much every language with polymorphism support does so. And why shouldn't they? What would you want to do with during normal programming anyway? Java's `instanceof` is of a similar quality than dynamic_cast – usually you should not need it. But as usual there might be exceptions. Would you want to refactor an entire large type hierarchy just because you discover one single type requiring special handling that is not covered by the common interface? Pragmatism…