# Casting a class to a class

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

[embedded C person here, boggled by embedded C++]

There is a class that derives from another, as follows:

```
class DerivedThing: public BaseThing {
...
}
```

There is some code, which I have no control over, which takes in a pointer to `DerivedThing` and, eventually, *casts* that pointer to `BaseThing`.  I'm led to believe this works.  Anyway, I need to implement my own `DerivedThing` but it needs to subclass some other stuff:

```
class MyDerivedThing: public BaseThing, public AnotherThing {
...
}
```

What do I need to do to make sure that the cast will still work?  I'm asking because in my case the wrong functions are most definitely being invoked.

EDIT: The cast in the code I have no control over is:

```
int setInterface(void* context)
{
    interface[0] = (BaseThing *) context;
    ...
```

Comment: I see no reason why that cast would stop working. How do you know the wrong functions are being invoked? _What_ functions are being invoked, _where_, and through what kind of pointer? Where is the code/commentary showing what should happen vs what happens instead? Also, the `c++` tag is missing.

Comment: I can tell that the wrong functions are being invoked because when I single step through this in the debugger a call to `BaseThing::a()` ends up in `BaseThing::z()` instead.  The eventual cast of `MyDerivedThing` to `BaseThing` is done several levels down (in the code that I have no control over), going via `void *` on the way, so unless the relevant bits are identical in memory it's gonna mess up.  I have to make sure that the `BaseThing` parts of `DerivedThing` and `MyDerivedThing` are in the same place and I can't see how the compiler can do that for me.

Comment: And still there is nowhere near to enough information here to work with. How is the cast done? A proper `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` will have no problem casting between related classes for which all declarations are available and consistent. The compiler **will** do that for you as and when needed. Otherwise, inheritance and virtual functions could never work, could they? But if someone somewhere is rolling their own unsafe casts, then all bets are off, but that's not the compiler's fault at all. So, again: who's doing the cast, and how? It sounds like they're doing it wrongly and unsafely

Comment: That's the bit I have no control over.  I'll edit the original question to include it.

Comment: Right, that's not a C++ cast. It's a C cast from `void*`. It's not going to work to cast between related classes unless they're singly inherited & non-virtual. Otherwise casts among related classes can only be done if the compiler knows the definitions of source + destination types & is instructed to do an intelligent `static_` or `dynamic_cast`. I _guess_ you can _try_ casting yourself before passing: cast your more derived type to whatever derived type the function expects. But again, I don't think that's under any obligation to work. I'd say use a better API, or use this one differently.

Comment: Many thanks, that's clear then.  I'll go see if I can find someone who controls that code...

Comment: That's worth a shot, but the real answer might be the difficult one: don't do what you're currently trying to do. :P But in seriousness, I would ask them why that `context` pointer is a `void*` and not a `BaseThing*`, since the function immediately casts the former to the latter. Were the function declared to take a `BaseThing*`, then the compiler would have a fighting chance of being able to adjust the cast properly and achieve your desired result. Failing that, you might have to alter your design. Good luck anyway!

Comment: If you know that it's always going to be cast to `BaseThing*`, then cast your `DerivedThing*` to a `BaseThing*` when you call `setInterface`.  This will ensure the pointer is fixed up correctly.  Also, slap whoever wrote that function, it's clear not actually a `void*`.  He should really just be taking a `BaseThing*` into it.

Comment: You can create an object `MyDerivedThing`, print out its address, then create a pointer of type `BaseThing` to that same object via `BaseThing* p = &myobject;` and print out that address as well. If those two addresses are the same, I would expect the code to work. If not, then it won't. Maybe that clarifies why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was overly pessimistic while commenting!

Casting to `BaseThing*` yourself, and passing *that* to the function taking `void*`, should work.

The problem with just passing the address of derived object, as-is, is that its address gets implicitly converted to a `void*`. As a result, all information about its type and the involved class hierarchy is lost.

The receiving function then assumes the now-`void*` pointer pointed directly at a `BaseThing`. This is where things start to go loopy, manifesting as symptoms like the wrong functions being called - *if you're lucky* - because assuming that the derived object and any particular base subobject have the same address is not (always/reliably) a valid assumption where multiple and/or virtual inheritance are at play.

Intermission: It's not immediately clear why this quoted order of bases would cause a problem:

```
class MyDerivedThing: public BaseThing, public AnotherThing {
```

...but there are various possibilities. For example, if all three classes here have no virtual methods, then there shouldn't be a problem. But, for example, if `BaseThing` was not virtual but either of the other two is, the compiler might put a virtual table pointer at the top of the object, which will blow up anything that just takes that address and assumes there's a `BaseThing` there.

Anyway - by casting yourself before passing, the compiler can do a proper type-aware cast, performing any adjusting arithmetic that might be required, to the address of the `BaseThing` within your object - then pass that to the function. It still goes through the conversion to `void*` and back, but that'll now be guaranteed to represent the address of a `BaseThing` in the end.

I'd still question the author on why this function takes a `void*`. One of the key things about C++ is type safety. `void*` makes a mockery of that. Worse, they just cast said `void*` to a `BaseThing*` immediately anyway. So, why not just... take a `BaseThing*` in the first place? Then the compiler could implicitly perform the mentioned safe typecast at any call site, rather than making you do it.

Comment: I can confirm that there are indeed compilers that put a vtable pointer before base classes.  MSVC tries to make sure its vtable pointer, `{vfptr}` is always the first entity in any class that needs a vtable; it will either put `{vfptr}` before the bases (if no non-virtual base has one) or move the first base with a vftable pointer to the front of the object (in multiple inheritance, when at least one non-virtual base has one).  [If only virtual bases have vtables, and no new virtual functions are declared, it doesn't do any reordering.]  It does something similar for its virtual base table.

Comment: @JustinTime Thanks! I presumed such things occurred but hadn't specifically seen them in action, as for my own uses, I prefer the low level stuff to be an opaque abstraction in this case. :D So it's great to have detailed info on what kind of things can go on, from someone who has looked at it. Maybe some day I'll investigate what GCC does here...

Comment: You're welcome.  I found out about it while I was looking at how it mangles names, when I was trying to figure out how one of its special helper entities worked; I ended up getting distracted and looking at how it handles class layout.  You can make it output layouts with [hidden options `d1reportAllClassLayout` and `d1reportSingleClassLayoutX`](https://ofekshilon.com/2010/11/07/d1reportallclasslayout-dumping-object-memory-layout/), where `X` is all or part of the name of the class(es) whose layout you want to see.

Comment: I would imagine it's easier to find info about GCC, since it's open-source.  I'm not sure if it's actually documented anywhere, but there's [at least one SO answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28155780/5386374), and probably some about `-fdump-class-hierarchy` as well.